# Transformation of random variable involving projectile distance

Tags: statistics, random-variables, transformation

Problem:

Suppose a projectile is ﬁred at an angle $θ$ from the horizontal with a velocity $v$. The horizontal distance that the projectile travels, $R$, is given by

$$R = \frac{v^2}{g} \sin 2 \theta$$

where $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity ($9.8$ m/s2)

If $ \theta$ is uniformly distributed over the range $(0,π/4)$, ﬁnd the probability density function of $R$.

. . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

I know the answer involves the change of variable method. I get as far as solving the Jacobian derived to be $\dfrac{2v^2\cos2\theta}{g}$. At this point I am unsure how to proceed further to achieve the answer  which is given as $\dfrac{2g}{\pi\sqrt{v4-g^2r^2}}$ for $0 < r <v^2/g$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the probability density function of $R$ means here in terms of physics ? Is it the probability function $p_X(x)$ to have crossed any distance from $0$ to $x$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $0<\theta < \pi/4$, this means that $0< 2\theta< \pi/2$, and the $\sin$ function is monotonic increasingly in this interval, you can then use the fact that if $p_X(x)$ represents the PDF of a random variable $X$ and $Y = f(X)$ is another random variable, then the PDF of $Y$ satisfies

$$
p_X(x)dx = p_Y(y)dy ~~~\Rightarrow p_Y(y) = p_X(x)\left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|
$$

where the absolute value is there to ensure that $p_Y$ is well defined. In your case we have $x = \theta$ and $y = R = v^2 g^{-1}\sin 2\theta$, therefore

$$
\frac{gR}{v^2} = \sin 2\theta ~~~\Rightarrow~~~ \theta(R) = \frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{gR}{v^2}\right)
$$

so that the derivative is

$$
\frac{d\theta(R)}{dR} = \frac{g}{2v^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - g^2R^2/v^4}} = \frac{g}{2\sqrt{v^4 - g^2R^2}} ~~~\mbox{for}~~~ 0 < R < v^2/g
$$

Finally, since $\theta$ is uniformly distributed, we have $p_\Theta(\theta) = 1/(\pi/4) = 4/\pi$ for $0<\theta< \pi/4$, and $0$ otherwise. Putting eveything together

$$
p(R) = \frac{2g}{\pi\sqrt{v^4 - g^2R^2}} ~~~\mbox{for}~~~ 0 < R < v^2/g
$$

Comment: Great answer. Would you mind explaining how you determined the derivative to be $ \frac {g}{2\sqrt{v^4-g^2R^2}} $ and the range for the derivative as $0 < r < v^2 / g$

Comment: @Praxis The derivative is a well known property

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\sin^{-1}x = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}
$$

and the range comes from the fact that $0 < \sin 2\theta < 1$ for $0< \theta< 1$, so $0<v^2g^{-1}\sin2\theta < v^2/g$

Comment: I just want to learn but why does the PDF of $Y$ satisfies

$$p_X(x)dx = p_Y(y)dy$$

Comment: @Praxis Intuitively speaking, the number of events in the interval $p_X(x){\rm d}x$ should be the same regardless of the variable you use to label them. More formally you can find a justification for that equation following [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Probability/Transformation_of_Probability_Densities) link

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Go the other way, i.e. write $\theta$ as a function of $r$: $\theta = v(r)$ the change of variable formula gives $f_R(r) = f_\theta (v(r)) |v'(r)|$ where $f_R$ is the distribution function for $R$ and $f_\theta = 4 / \pi$ and is uniform.